# How can I make FlashBuilder use a custom namespace prefix

Tags: apache-flex, namespaces, flash-builder, manifest

I have a component library. It has a manifest file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<componentPackage>
    <component id="AutoComplete" class="be.edge.components.AutoComplete" />
    <!-- more components left out for brevity -->
</componentPackage>
```

I compile the library through FlashBuilder with these compiler settings:

[image: FlashBuilder library compiler namespace inputs]

When I use the compiled library in other FlashBuilder projects everything works as expected. I get code completion and when I select a suggestion from the code completion a namespace attribute is automatically added to the component, like this:

```
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:ns="library://ns.edge.be" >

    <ns:AutoComplete />

</s:Skin>
```

**But:** FlashBuilder automatically creates the prefix 'ns'. I would like to customize this to 'e' for instance. How can I make FlashBuilder use this custom prefix by default?

I have two reasons for this:

1. 'ns' doesn't say anything: it just says *A namespace* has been used, not what namespace.
2. when I use other libraries that also start with a url like 'library://ns.' FlashBuilder will probably start numbering the prefixes to resolve the conflict (ns, ns1, ns2, etc.), which would be even more confusing.

**EDIT:**

I also pass a config.xml to the compiler that has the following declarations relating to namespaces:

```
<compiler>
    <namespaces>
        <namespace>
            <uri>library://ns.edge.be</uri>
            <manifest>manifest.xml</manifest>
        </namespace>
    </namespaces>
</compiler>

<include-namespaces>
    <uri>library://ns.edge.be</uri>
</include-namespaces>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This *used* to work:

Create a file called `design.xml` in your /src folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<design>
    <namespaces>
        <namespace prefix="mangos" uri="http://com.mangofactory.sample/mxml/2010" />
    </namespaces>
</design>
```

Create a file called `manifest.xml` in your /src folder:

```
<componentPackage>
        <component id="MyClass" class="com.mangofactory.framework.MyClassTag"/>
</componentPackage>
```

Configure your Namespace URL, etc in the build properties:
[image]

This is *supposed* to cause flash builder to prompt as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:mangos="http://com.mangofactory.sample/mxml/2010">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <mangos:MyClass />
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:Application>
```

(Note that the class appears as `MyClass` instead of `MyClassTag`, and the namespace appears as `mangos`)

However, I just tried doing this, and although the class was renamed correctly, the namespace appeared up as `ns`.  I know this used to work in FB3.x, maybe I've either forgotten a step, or FB4.5 has broken it.

Comment: I tried, hoping that it would magically work on my system. But it doesn't. Shouldn't you reference that design.xml somewhere though? Otherwise the compiler couldn't know about it. (I'll add some more compiler info to my question.)

Comment: I also tried adding `prefix="e"` to the `namespace` tag in my config.xml, to no avail (I don't get an error though).

Comment: Aha! Just found the missing part: you have to include the design.xml file in the swc by ticking its checkbox under the 'Assets' tab in 'Flex Library Build Path'. You got me there, so I'll accept your answer.

Comment: And, if you want to generate the manifest.xml (cause there can be a lot of components >_<), there is a goal : [FlexMojos : Manifest generation](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/FLEXMOJOS/Manifest+generation)

Comment: I just tried this in FB 4.7 and it seems to be broken.. maybe because the design.xml was intended for "design view" instrumentation, and this feature was removed since 4.7? Anyone have this working on FB 4.7?

Answer (score 0):

If you just change `xmlns:ns` to `xmlns:e` or `xmlns:foo` then the MXML parser will pick up on the change.  It's not all that difficult to change, and I don't think there is a way to change how it generates namespaces by default.

Comment: I know, but I just grow tired of changing it every single time I create a new mxml component.

Comment: I poked around in the preferences, and I don't see anything that would allow you to change this.  You'd probably have to replace some java class in the plugin modify this behavior.  Hopefully somebody will come up with a better answer for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, FlashBuilder isn't open-source, so that would be pretty hard. Some tinkering with code templates perhaps?

Comment: I looked a bit in the catalog.xml for the various framework library SWC files to see if there was some extra tag that that indicated a default namespace, but I couldn't find one.  By code templates do you mean the File Templates under the Flash Builder preferences?

Comment: If it would be a library attribute, I suppose you would pass it in as a command line option (as you do for the url), but I couldn't find any info on that. As for the templates: yes that's what I mean. There's an `xmlns` variable and `ns_prefix`, but I'm not sure I can use that. Unless I add the namespace to _every_ component of course.